# Jenkins Azure Blob Storage plugin to copy the contents of Build folder and not build folder to $web azure blob static cotainer

Tags: windows, azure, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, azure-blob-storage

We are using Jenkins Azure Blob plugin to deploy into Azure Blob Storage and have to use $web hosting feature in Azure.what happens is while mentioning the folder like build/* , this is copying the entire build folder into $web container instead of the files inside the build folder. As per the Azure static web hosting, the document index file will be only pointed to index.html under $web i.e. $web/index.html, but in this case it is coming as $web/build/index.html which we don't want. This build folder can't be configure in the Azure Web static hosting and it has to be in the root as there are couple of files which comes as relative path automatically after build.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-storage-static-web-hosting-public-preview/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-java-jenkins-continuous-integration-solution

Please can someone check and responds..

Thanks

Comment: It is still an open issue for now: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-57478?jql=text%20~%20%22windows-azure-storage-plugin%22

Answer (score 1):

Just use the dir command to run the Azure Storage inside your root folder, and remove the folder from the parameter:

```
dir('build'){
   azureUpload blobProperties: … filesPath: '**/'
}
```